# Golang - Parsing JSON string arrays from Twitch TV RESTful service

Tags: json, go

I've been working on parsing a JSON object that I retrieve through an HTTP GET request using Go's built in HTTP library. I initially tried using the default JSON library in Go in order to do this, but I was having a difficult time (I am a novice in Go still). I eventually resorted to using a different library and had little trouble after that, as shown below:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/antonholmquist/jason"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/deernadia/chatters")
    if nil != err {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := jason.NewObjectFromReader(resp.Body)

    chatters, err := body.GetObject("chatters")
    if nil != err {
        panic(err)
    }

    moderators, err := chatters.GetStringArray("moderators")
    if nil != err {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, moderator := range moderators {
        fmt.Println(moderator)
    }
}
```

Where `github.com/antonholmquist/jason` corresponds to the custom JSON library I used.

This code produces something similar to the following output when run in a Linux shell (the RESTful service will update about every 30 seconds or so, which means the values in the JSON object will potentially change):

```
antwan250
bbrock89
boxception22
cmnights
deernadia
fartfalcon
fijibot
foggythought
fulc_
h_ov
iceydefeat
kingbobtheking
lospollogne
nightbot
nosleeptv
octaviuskhan
pateyy
phosphyg
poisonyvie
shevek18
trox94
trox_bot
uggasmesh
urbanelf
walmartslayer
wift3
```

And the raw JSON looks similar to this (with some of the users removed for brevity):

```
{
  "_links": {},
  "chatter_count": 469,
  "chatters": {
    "moderators": [
      "antwan250",
      "bbrock89",
      "boxception22",
      "cmnights",
      "deernadia",
      "fartfalcon",
      "fijibot",
      "foggythought",
      "fulc_",
      "h_ov",
      "iceydefeat",
      "kingbobtheking",
      "lospollogne",
      "nightbot",
      "nosleeptv",
      "octaviuskhan",
      "pateyy",
      "phosphyg",
      "poisonyvie",
      "shevek18",
      "trox94",
      "trox_bot",
      "uggasmesh",
      "urbanelf",
      "walmartslayer",
      "wift3"
    ],
    "staff": [
      "tnose"
    ],
    "admins": [],
    "global_mods": [],
    "viewers": [
      "03xuxu30",
      "0dominic0",
      "3389942",
      "812mfk",
      "910dan",
      "aaradabooti",
      "admiralackbar99",
      "adrian97lol",
      "aequitaso_o",
      "aethiris",
      "afropigeon",
      "ahhhmong",
      "aizaix",
      "aka_magosh",
      "akitoalexander",
      "alex5761",
      "allenhei",
      "allou_fun_park",
      "amilton_tkm",
      "... more users that I removed...",
      "zachn17",
      "zero_x1",
      "zigslip",
      "ziirbryad",
      "zonato83",
      "zorr03body",
      "zourtv"
    ]
  }
}
```

As I said before, I'm using a custom library hosted on Github in order to accomplish what I needed, but **for the sake of learning**, I'm curious... how would I accomplish this same thing using Go's built in JSON library?

To be clear, what I'd like to do is be able to harvest the users from each JSON array embedded within the JSON object returned from the HTTP GET request. I'd also like to be able to get the list of viewers, admins, global moderators, etc., in the same way, but I figured that if I can see the moderator example using the default Go library, then reproducing that code for the other user types will be trivial.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With encoding/json you have to define a struct type with the right fields (and json field tags if your fields in code don't match the json field names), declare a variable of that struct type and then pass a pointer to that variable to the json.Unmarshal function along with the json in byte slice form. Start with the Unmarshal function on some simple examples (refer to the godoc for json).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to unmarshal moderators only, use the following:

```
var v struct {
    Chatters struct {
        Moderators []string
    }
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
 for _, mod := range v2.Chatters.Moderators {
    fmt.Println(mod)
}
```

If you want to get all types of chatters, use the following:

```
var v struct {
    Chatters map[string][]string
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
    handle error
}
for kind, users := range v1.Chatters {
    for _, user := range users {
        fmt.Println(kind, user)
    }
}
```

<kbd>[run the code on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/VHNff5Wf0y)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!